# SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$db_dns='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=thedjsai_elitsafe';
$db_user='thedjsai_elitsf';
$db_pass='password';

try
{
    $db_conn=new PDO($db_dns, $db_user, $db_pass);
} catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage(); exit();
}
```

Возвращает SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'thedjsai_elitsf'@'localhost' to database 'thedjsai_elitsafe'

Причем через phpMyAdmin заходит. Логин и пароль точно верны. Права все есть.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте использовать 127.0.0.1 вместо localhost. С точки зрения БД это разные значения.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно помогло